# Using libcurl in web site login authentication

Tags: authentication, libcurl

While using libcurl (and Fiddler for debugging), I have come across the following scenario:
This JSON was received in a response to pre-authentication:

```
algorithm=sha256-mod-v1
algorithmParameters
n=200 
r=0
authFlow=password
sessionId=5425faa0-b131-4c47-9d36-9daeb68bd54cqgWOnNNYlwDkF7ZJHYw=
```

My browser (Firefox and Chrome) sends this JSON back as part of the authentication step:

```
password=password  preAuthToken=eyJrZXkiOjEzNSwic2Vzc2lvbl9pZCI6IjU0MjVmYWEwLWIxMzEtNGM0Ny05ZDM2LTlkYWViNjhiZDU0Y3FnV09uTk5ZbHdEa0Y3WkpIWXc9Iiwic29sdXRpb25faGFzaCI6Ijg0M2ZlOWZlZjA4NWM1MWMzNWY1ZDQ3ZjRmMWYzYWQwOTA2NmUxMTE5NzBiN2ZiYmY5YTUwZjQwN2NkMTQ3ODgiLCJzb2x1dGlvbl90aW1lX21zIjo5fQ==
username=username
```

Decoding the preAuthToken, I see this:

```json
{"key":135,"session_id":"5425faa0-b131-4c47-9d36-9daeb68bd54cqgWOnNNYlwDkF7ZJHYw=","solution_hash":"843fe9fef085c51c35f5d47f4f1f3ad09066e111970b7fbbf9a50f407cd14788","solution_time_ms":9}
```

The session_id variable makes sense but I don’t understand any of the other variables – any ideas of what they mean or what I can do to get valid authentication? Is the solution_hash some sort of has of the session id? And, if so, how can I code for that in a C program?

I am able to successfully login in with any browser but am unable to figure out what the browser is doing successfully that I am unable to mimic in the code.

Thanks.